# Continuous query to calculate difference in InfluxDB

Tags: sql, influxdb, continuous

Most common use for continuous query is to calculate average etc.

```
CREATE CONTINUOUS QUERY minnie ON world BEGIN SELECT min(mouse) INTO min_mouse FROM zoo GROUP BY time(30m) END
```

I have data points with increment values
I am attempting to calculate the difference in value in every interval.

```
INSERT mydb value=4  1470101034546846145
INSERT mydb value=8  1470101042290558132
INSERT mydb value=10 1470101043594271416
```

I want to get 10 - 4 = 6 for example.

Is there a way to achieve this using continuous query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the new `DIFFERENCE()` function in your query:
https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v0.13/query_language/functions/#difference

`SELECT DIFFERENCE(<function>(<field_key>)) FROM <measurement_name> WHERE <stuff> GROUP BY time(<time_interval>)`

This is available since v0.13 I think.

Answer (score 1):

Your options are

- `DIFFERENCE()` for sequential differences. In you example, `DIFFERENCE(mouse)` would give 8-4, 10-8, etc. This might be useful for you, but doesn't fit your description.
- `SPREAD()`:  seems to be what you're looking for, which is shorthand for `MAX(mouse) - MIN(mouse)` on the interval. So something like:  `SELECT SPREAD(mouse) AS "mouse_range" INTO mouse_calcs FROM zoo GROUP BY time(30m)`, where `mouse_range` and `mouse_calcs` are names I picked with no special meaning.